# Multipurpose Payroll System C

Tags: c, struct, unions

I have a program using unions and structures that calculates pay for an hourly worker or a salary worker. For an hourly worker the hours they work must be less than 80. I implemented that in my code but I get this warning and do not know how to fix it. [image: This is the Warning I get]

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXSIZE 4000

union Employee { //union
    struct HourlyPaid { //Struct for Hourly Workers
        char name[20];
        char Gender[20];
        int HoursWorked;
        float HourlyRate;
    } HourlyPaid;

    struct Salary { //struct for Salaried workers
        char name[50];
        int age;
        float salary;
        float bonus;
    } Salary;
} Employee;
    int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0; 
    char option[2];
    char s[MAXSIZE];    
    while(1)
    {
        puts("\nMULTIPURPOSE PAYROLL SYSTEM");
        puts("Please Select an Option to Continue:");
        puts("Option A: Calculating Pay for an HOURLY worker");
        puts("Option B: Calculating Pay for an SALARIED worker\n"); 
        puts("PRESS ANY OTHER BUTTON TO EXIT\n");
        fgets(option, MAXSIZE, stdin);
        //putchar(option);

        if((option[0]=='a')||(option[0]=='A')) //Condition for Hourly Workers
        {
            puts("Please enter how many salaries you wish to input:\t");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            struct HourlyPaid x[n];

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {   
                fputs("Enter Name: ", stdout);
                scanf("%s", x[i].name);

                fputs("Enter Gender: ", stdout);
                scanf("%s", x[i].Gender);

                fputs("Enter Hours Worked: ", stdout);
                scanf("%d", &x[i].HoursWorked);

                fputs("Enter Hourly Rate: ", stdout);
                scanf("%f", &x[i].HourlyRate);
            }

            if (&x[i].HoursWorked > 80 )
            {
                puts ("Sorry please enter a value less than 80 for hours worked");             
            }
else
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                printf("\n\tCalculated Salary #%d\n", (i+1));
                puts("\t===============================");
                printf("\n\tName %d.............%s \n", (i+1),x[i].name);
                printf("\tGender %d...........%s \n", (i+1), x[i].Gender);
                printf("\tHours Worked %d.....%d \n", (i+1), x[i].HoursWorked);
                printf("\tHourly Rate %d......%.2f \n", (i+1), x[i].HourlyRate);
                printf("\n\tTotal Salary %d.....%.2f \n", (i+1), (x[i].HourlyRate*x[i].HoursWorked));
                puts("\t===============================");
            } //End of for
        } //End of if

        else if((option[0]=='b')||(option[0]=='B')) //Condition for Salaried Workers
        {       
            puts("Please enter how many salaries you wish to input:\t");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            struct Salary x[n];
            //int i;
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {               
                printf("Enter Name %d: ", i+1);
                scanf("%s", x[i].name);

                printf("Enter Age %d: ", i+1);
                scanf("%d", &x[i].age);

                printf("Enter Salary %d: ", i+1);
                scanf("%f", &x[i].salary);

                printf("Enter Bonus %d: ", i+1);
                scanf("%f", &x[i].bonus);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                printf("\n\tCalculated Salary #%d\n", (i+1));
                puts("\t============================");
                printf("\n\tName %d is..........%s \n", (i+1),x[i].name);
                printf("\tAge %d is...........%d \n", (i+1), x[i].age);
                printf("\tSalary %d is........%.2f \n", (i+1), x[i].salary);
                printf("\tBonus %d is.........%.2f \n", (i+1), x[i].bonus);
                printf("\n\tTotal Pay %d is.....%.2f \n", (i+1), (x[i].bonus+x[i].salary));
                puts("\t============================");
            }
        } //End of else if
        else
        {
             return 0;
        }
            fgets(option, MAXSIZE, stdin);
    } //End of While
} //End of Main
```

Comment: why are you having `&` in front of `x`? do you mean to use the pointer? I think you need `if (x[i].HoursWorked > 80 )`

Comment: @bansi the if statement will not work if i remove the address sign .

Comment: you also have a messed up loop. the `if ....` block should be inside `for` loop. otherwise it will always be checking for `n+1`th value

Comment: the title is about what you're asking, not what your project name is

Comment: &x[i] is not required, you can simply use x[i]. The value of i after the for loop ends is an incremented value(i++), and hence x[i].HoursWorked is 0 . Therefore you are thinking that your if statement is not working.

Comment: You write _the if statement will not work if i remove the address sign_. What do you mean by _will not work_ ? Did you try to put a `printf("%d\n, x[i].HoursWorked);` right before the `if`?

Comment: And BTW: the title of your question is totally unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        for(i = 0; i < n; ) // note no i++ here
        {   
            fputs("Enter Name: ", stdout);
            scanf("%s", x[i].name);

            fputs("Enter Gender: ", stdout);
            scanf("%s", x[i].Gender);

            fputs("Enter Hours Worked: ", stdout);
            scanf("%d", &x[i].HoursWorked);

            fputs("Enter Hourly Rate: ", stdout);
            scanf("%f", &x[i].HourlyRate);

            if (x[i].HoursWorked > 80 )
            {
                puts ("Sorry please enter a value less than 80 for hours worked");             
            } else {
                i++; //note increment i only if the value is good 
            }
        }
```

This is not an ideal solution. you may need to enter all details again if `HoursWorked > 80`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it *does not* work is not related to the presence or the absene of the `&`sign, but because your logic is a bit awkward.

You want this:

```
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    fputs("Enter Name: ", stdout);
    scanf("%s", x[i].name);

    fputs("Enter Gender: ", stdout);
    scanf("%s", x[i].Gender);

    fputs("Enter Hours Worked: ", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &x[i].HoursWorked);

    do
    {
      fputs("Enter Hourly Rate: ", stdout);
      scanf("%f", &x[i].HourlyRate);

      if (x[i].HoursWorked > 80)
      {
        puts("Sorry please enter a value less than 80 for hours worked\n");
        continue;
      }
    } while (0);
  }
```

If the user enters a number greater then 80, the program simply displays `"Sorry, please..."` and then asks the user again to enter the number of hours worked.